# flatbuffer: failed to serialize array by python api ? TypeError: EndVector() missing 1 required positional argument: 'vectorNumElems'

Tags: python-3.x, flatbuffers

i try to use python to serialize, but failed.

```
    table Test {
        test1: [string];
    }

    builder = flatbuffers.Builder(0)
    self.test.test1 = list()
    self.test.test1.append('123')
    self.test.Pack(builder)
```

Comment: you are using generated code that is newer than the runtime code. make sure they're all from the same version.

Comment: I regenerate code before running py, and i try different python version, it still does not work.

Comment: like I said, you have a mismatch with your runtime code. Make sure you use the runtime version that comes from the same version as where you got `flatc` from, do not mix versions from github/pip/pypi etc.